# Where do I put these header/c files or libraries that I just downloaded? (C++, MinGW)

Tags: c++, windows, header, mingw

I haven't used online libraries before this.

I just downloaded libzip from https://libzip.org/ (was looking for c++ file to unzip zip files)

I now have this nice folder that's called libzip-1.5.2.

Where do I put it? I'm using mingw to compile, and just emacs to write.

I've tried copy and pasting it into mingw's various bin folders, lib folders, include folders, etc. A great variety of places within the C://mingw root folder. None of them work.

No matter where I look, every single question glosses over this, just saying "just include zip.h" but never mentioning how to actually set it up.

I guess this could be generalized to: I have a bunch of .c and .h files from a library I downloaded for my compiler. Where do I put them so that I don't get:

> "fatal error: header.h No such file or directory"

Again, I use MinGW/G++ to compile, and just Emacs for writing. I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: Not too familiar with Mingw, but did the library come with installation instructions, or an installation script to run?

Comment: It includes a `cmake` based build system. Install cmake and run it. Read the install.md.

Answer (score 0):

Put it somewhere with an simple pathname. You have to tell g++ where to find the libraries and the headers. Normally this is done with the -L and -I option. Maybe you have to compile the library first. There you have to look at the install instructions.